# Unable to reformat SD-card to ext4

Tags: partitioning, mount, ext4, sd-card

**edit: I solved the problem by using a USB drive instead**

**OS**: ubuntu 20.04 (headless)
**Hardware**: Beaglebone Black

My beaglebone black (BBB) has too little space to install some software I need. Therefore I want to transfer /usr to my sd-card (I know theres more steps, but i didnt get to that yet)

When I tried to rsync my /usr to my mounted sd-card i realized the FAT32 file system doesnt support ownership, and that ext4 is recommended.

I tried following this tutorial: https://kwilson.io/blog/format-a-linux-disk-as-ext4-from-the-command-line/

It finished with no errors:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 7633152 4k blocks and 1908736 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 83a33f63-271f-44e0-a4a7-cb6df8535f4e
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

However, when checking with fdisk -l, it doesnt say its ext4!

```
Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *     8192 61067230 61059039 29.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

On top of that, I get this error when I try to mount it:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/sdcard
mount: /mnt/sdcard: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How can I succesfully format it to ext4 or something else that will fullfill my goals?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You didn't change the partition type before you put the filesystem on it, so it was left as 7.  Shouldn't cause a problem -- try explicitly giving the -t ext4 arguments to your mount.

Comment: You mean writing "ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1" ?

I tried it now and i got the same result. Maybe i misunderstood you though.

Comment: sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/sdcard    But just to avoid confusion in the future, you probably should also change the partition type to 83 with a tool like gparted or gdisk.